# How do I hide bullets in LaTeX lists?

Tags: latex

Semantically, I want an itemized list, but visually I just want some space.  How can I hide the bullets?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I can't speak for any other setup, but I'm using Tufte-Latex on MacTex, and I just typed the following:

`\begin{itemize}[]`

It worked. :-) I love it when guessing does that. So just try adding `[]` after.

P.S. the "generalized" list from lindelof worked also, but they didn't line up as nicely as with itemize. Jakub's suggestion was what inspired my guess, when I tried it, I got a bunch of "label=" strings as bullet points.

Edit: As others have pointed out, the more standard approach is to again use [], but next to each item in the list as in other answers on this page. If you tire of seeing square brackets on each line, try other approaches on this page :)

```
\begin{description}
\item[] first item
\end{description}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. (I'm not sure of the precise details of my installation, but I don't think it is unusual.) The answer below by Clueso is a more standard solution.

Comment: Sure. As I implied, I was guessing. ;-) I suspect I might have been relying on enumitem ... or some non-standard behaviour. Who knows. To future searchers, please try whatever seems best/most standard to you :p Personally I'd get tired of typing [] after each \item, so the macro suggestion might also be worth investigating. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: this hasn't worked for me. See the answer below or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50269/itemize-without-bullets for a few options. (The answer below should probably be accepted as the answer since the current one may be misleading.)

Comment: Edited my answer, since I can't change what's been accepted :)

Answer (score 75):

```
\item[] text
```

Optionally, you can put something inside the [].

Answer (score 29):

My response is quite late for this thread but thought I will add it for the benefit of any future searchers.

I accomplished this by using the description environment and using blanks for the \item commands.

e.g

```
\begin{description}
\item[] first item
\end{description}
```

That worked fine for me.

Answer (score 10):

What you probably want is a generalized list:

```
\begin{list}{\quad}{}
\item ...
\end{list}
```

The second argument to this environment is the symbol that will be inserted in front of every item.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best solution would be to use [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package from CTAN: It is present in teTeX and LaTex and should also be present in most other TeX distribution. Then you are able to use:

```
\begin{itemize}[label=]
\item 1st item
\item ...
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 8):

The bullet itself is a macro so you can easily redefine it globally like this:

`\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\star$}`

In your case just leave the macro empty. See [this page](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/teTeX/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-250.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the space, rather than a list environment you could use the tabbing environment

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{30pt}\=\hspace{30pt}\=\kill 
\> First Item\\
\> Second item\\
\> Third item
\end{tabbing}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in several ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% 1st way

\begin{itemize}
  \item[] First.
  \item[] Second.
\end{itemize}

% 2nd way    
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}

% 3rd way
{\renewcommand\labelitemi{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```